# Как найти минимальное число среди массива чисел?

Tags: javascript

Надо найти минимальное среди массива числа с помощью for или другого цикла Вот мой код:

```
var firstNumber = [3,0,-5,1,44,-12,3,0,0,1,2,-3,-3,2,1,4,-2-3-1];

var min = firstNumber[0];
var max = min;
for (i = -100; i > firstNumber.length; ++i) {
  if (firstNumber[i] < max) max = firstNumber[i];
  if (firstNumber[i] > min) min = firstNumber[i];

}
 console.log(firstNumber);
```

Comment: минимальное число - `-12`

Comment: @Grundy уверен??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript/40026552

Comment: А это точно твой код? Можешь рассказать что именно ты в нем делаешь?

Comment: Зачем знать мой код или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу в вопросе 2-ух массивов, но, предположим, что они есть.

```js
let arr1 = [-10, 12, -12, 40, 35, 100]
let arr2 = [-100, 81, 0, 1, 1, -101.2];

let min = Math.min(...arr1.concat(arr2));
console.log(min);
```